# How to use 2 different bootstrap theme in one angular 7 project?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7

I have 2 modules : Admin and User.
Both have 2 different theme of bootstrap like in admin pages i am using "CoreUI" and for user pages i use "Light bootstrap dashboard" theme. 
But when i use all css and js files in index.html then style sheets and js are conflicts and design is not displayed properly in any pages.

So can i use 2 different themes in one angular project?

Comment: I found the solution. To load js al set javascripts of both theme in index.html and define the css in component definition.

Sometimes some css can't be loaded which are defined in styleUrls of component definition so i set those styles sheets like this : 

$("body").append("<link id='bootstrapCssLink' rel="stylesheet" href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>");

When another component load in which different theme is used i removed bootstrap css like this : $("#bootstrapCssLink").remove();

This solution work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, styles are scoped to the component through an emulated Shadow DOM setup. Specify the styling in the [component definition](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) so

```
styleUrls: ['./yourBootstrapSheet.css']
```

and the elements in your template will be prepended with a unique id that matches a prefix applied to CSS elements behind the scenes

Comment: Is there any way to define used external javascript in component definition?